# caching images in collectionViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, parse-platform, uicollectionviewcell

I have images in my collectionViewCell's that are fetched and parsed via NSURLRequest, how do I cache these images so they don't have to start a new request with every single appearance/disappearance of the view?

here is my code that fetches the images:

```
class funnyPicture: NSObject {

    var pfPicture : PFObject
    var coverImage : UIImage!

    init(pfPicture: PFObject) {
        self.pfPicture = pfPicture
    }

    func fetchCoverImage(completion: (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        let urlString = self.pfPicture["funnyPictures"] as! String
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                self.coverImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                completion(image: self.coverImage, error: nil)
            } else {
                completion(image: nil, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my collectionView code that parse the images to the collectionViewCell's:

```
   override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

        // Configure the cell
        let book = self.books[indexPath.row]
        let coverImage = book.coverImage
        if coverImage == nil {
            book.fetchCoverImage({ (image, error) -> Void in
                if self.collectionView != nil {
                    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
                }
            })
        } else {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                let imageView = cell.imageView
                imageView.image = book.coverImage
            }
        };
        if book.coverImage == nil {
            cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }else {
            cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

        }

        return cell
    }
```

While I've received references to third party frameworks, I haven't received any answer on how to implement them with the code I have provided in the question, or even an answer using apples already implemented caching mechanism.. The reason I put the code in the question was for use in an answer.. Thank you.

Comment: you need to use DLImageLoader ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/19115912/294884

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example for your collection view cell:

```
import UIKit

let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>.sharedInstance

class myCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet public weak var myImageView: UIImageView?

    private var imageUrlString: String?

    private var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?
    public var imageURL: URL? {
        didSet {
            self.downloadItemImageForSearchResult(imageURL: imageURL)
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
    }

    public func downloadItemImageForSearchResult(imageURL: URL?) {

        if let urlOfImage = imageURL {
            if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlOfImage.absoluteString as NSString){
            self.myImageView!.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
        } else {
            let session = URLSession.shared
            self.downloadTask = session.downloadTask(
                with: urlOfImage as URL, completionHandler: { [weak self] url, response, error in
                    if error == nil, let url = url, let data = NSData(contentsOf: url), let image = UIImage(data: data as Data) {

                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {

                            let imageToCache = image

                            if let strongSelf = self, let imageView = strongSelf.myImageView {

                                imageView.image = imageToCache

                                imageCache.setObject(imageToCache, forKey: urlOfImage.absoluteString as NSString , cost: 1)
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //print("ERROR \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                    }
            })
            self.downloadTask!.resume()
        }
      }
    }

    override public func prepareForReuse() {
      self.downloadTask?.cancel()
      myImageView?.image = UIImage(named: "ImagePlaceholder")
    }

    deinit {
      self.downloadTask?.cancel()
      myImageView?.image = nil
    }
}
```

**Don't forget to make an extension for NSCache**
Like this:

```
import Foundation

extension NSCache {
  class var sharedInstance: NSCache<NSString, AnyObject> {
      let cache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
      return cache
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set total cost of NSCache!

Answer (score 1):

Use NSCache and NSOperationQueue to manage your image loading. There's a good post outlining the technique at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12721899/5271191 (It's Objective-C, but the technique is the same for Swift.)

Comment: yes i see, that method seems right but i have a small question

Comment: when I add the `var imageDownloadingQueue: NSOperationQueue` and
    `var imageCache: NSCache` variables, It says my class has no initializers.. why so?

Comment: and i have the following in my viewDidLoad                                                                    `self.imageDownloadingQueue = NSOperationQueue()`
        `self.imageDownloadingQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4`
        `self.imageCache = NSCache()` ... is that not initializing?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is called after the class is initialized, so it's not the same as an `init` function and Swift will throw a compile error when you try to initialize non-optional properties there. You can set the properties during the declaration to get around this, i.e. `var imageDownloadingQueue = NSOperationQueue()`.  Otherwise make them optionals and unwrap them when you go to use them.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend you to use a clean in place replacement/extension for UIImageView, that will manage caching of the image all transparently to you and avoid unwanted complexity of maintaining operation queues, etc.

If in memory caching suffices your needs - check this out-

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

If you want persistent caching, then this one will do-

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

HTH.

Comment: is there not any repos or tutorials written in swift?

Comment: You can include them in your swift project, and Xcode will take care of creating a bridge header, where you just need to #import the relevant headers..

Comment: Hey MikeStrong, take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577207/caching-images-in-collectionviewcell/32591457#32591457) (in regards to Swift)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a specialized framework for that. I would **not** recommend using SDWebImage, it is very outdated and is not stable.

Take a look at those two libraries that are up to date with iOS platform:

- [DFImageManager](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager) - advanced framework written in Objective-C but featuring nullability annotations (works great with Swift). Here's a [list of things](https://github.com/kean/DFImageManager/wiki/How-is-DFImageManager-better-than-SDWebImage) that make it better, than SDWebImage. **Disclosure:** it's written by me, opinion might be biased.
- [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) - lightweight library written in Swift. Similar to SDWebImage, but has much less features that SDWebImage and DFImageManager.

Comment: i just need a caching mechanism, I'm not looking to change the methods I use ti request and parse the images. So is it possible to just implement an external cache ?

Comment: Well, it is possible :) But this problem has been solved by multiple frameworks already (you can also throw AFNetworking, AlamofireImage, PINRemoteImage into the mix). There are a lot of things to take into consideration and those frameworks do all the heavy lifting for you. It's up to you to decide which one to use. Sorry, I would not help to reimplement this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

> I have images in my collectionViewCell's that are fetched and parsed
>   via NSURLRequest, how do I cache these images so they don't have to
>   start a new request with every single appearance/disappearance of the
>   view?

The [URL loading system](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) already provides a cache. Take a look at [the docs for NSURLCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/index.html). If the resources you need aren't already being sufficiently cached, you probably only need to adjust the disk space allocated to the URL cache for your app.

You should also take a look at the headers (cache-control, expires, etc.) that come back with your resources to make sure that they're not preventing caching. [Here's a short tutorial on cache-related headers.](http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/)

Answer (score -1):

I have created a library using swift 2 to do the request for image and cache it. it's very simple just give it a try.

https://github.com/georgehadly/GHImageCaching

all you can do is something like this ,

```
viewImg.getCachedImage("geo", URI: NSURL(string: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8e/5a/98/8e5a98795dc2c5322cac97343a6cad6d.jpg")!) { (done) -> Void in
        if(done){
            // your extra
        }
    }
```

in case you want to delete all cached images

```
UIImageView.deleteAllCaching()
```